# Trying to restore glacier deep archive to different s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I am trying to restore the glacier deep archive to a different s3 bucket, but when I run the below command getting error : fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "cf-ant-prod" does not exist

aws s3 cp s3://xxxxxxx/cf-ant-prod s3://xxxxxxx/atest --force-glacier-transfer --storage-class STANDARD --profile xxx

Comment: Are you sure you have the right name for the object? Please note that it only works on a single object, not a folder. (To restore a folder, you would need to include `--recursive`.

Comment: Yes I am trying to restore a folder, aws s3 cp s3://xxxxxxx/cf-ant-prod s3://xxxxxxx/atest --force-glacier-transfer --recursive --storage-class STANDARD --profile xxx. Hope this is the command I need to use?

Comment: I did some experimentation and found that the `--recursive` and `--force-glacier-transfer` had to be _before_ the filenames. However, I got the error: `Operation is not valid for the source object's storage class`. I know that Glacier retrievals normally take time, so I'm surprised that there is a "force-glacier-transfer" option. I suspect you will need to use `aws s3api restore-object` to move it (temporarily) out of the Glacier storage class so that it can be copied.

Comment: This StackOverflow answer suggests that it will only work on objects that have already been restored: [AWS S3 Sync --force-glacier-transfer - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676738/aws-s3-sync-force-glacier-transfer)

Comment: As suggest I am trying to use aws s3api, I do have aws MFA enabled so  when I try to run the below command aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket MYBUCKET --query "Contents[?StorageClass=='GLACIER']" --output text | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $2))}' | awk '{NF-=3};3' > glacier-restore.txt --profile xxx
getting error : awk: fatal: cannot open file `--profile' for reading (No such file or directory)

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Comment: That appears to be a different topic. Please create a new question.