# Is there a direct-to-S3 way to restore an object in GLACIER or DEEP_ARCHIVE storage class

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, recovery, amazon-glacier

I am trying to write a Python script that changes the storage class of an AWS S3 object from `GLACIER` or `DEEP_ARCHIVE` to `STANDARD`. The reverse is fairly easy to implement in a synchronous manner using the `s3_client.copy()` method and specifying the new storage class to, say, `DEEP_ARCHIVE`.

I understand that recovering from these "deep" classes requires the submission of a recovery request and after some time the data becomes available. That's perfectly clear.

However, I'm not able to make it work by following the official boto3 `restore_object` [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/object/restore_object.html#S3.Object.restore_object).

Here's my script:

```py
session = boto3.Session('...')
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')

obj = s3_resource.Object('my-bucket-name', 'file.txt')

response = obj.restore_object(
    RestoreRequest={
        'Tier': 'Expedited',
        'OutputLocation': {
            'S3': {
                'BucketName': 'my-bucket-name',
                'Prefix': 'file.txt',
                'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The error I keep getting is:

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the RestoreObject operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema`

Interestingly, using the `days` argument works fine, however, this is not what I want to achieve because neither will it permanently restore the data nor will the specific `key` actually switch to `STANDARD` class.

Having studied the aforementioned documentation, it is strongly suggested that what I want to achieve is supported.

This guy's [code at line 97](https://github.com/marko-bast/aws-s3-glacier-restore/blob/e3761b4afe75ea4843c1b1debbcd6502a1714d25/aws-s3-glacier-restore#L97) is similar to what I need but restores to a different bucket -- not sure if that's what makes the difference, assuming his code still works.

Comment: `OutputLocation` is only used to store the output of a S3 Select query.  In other words, really want you want to do is use the `days` argument, then _after_ the restore is complete, perform an S3 copy (you can copy to/from the same bucket and key), which will generate a new object in the desired non-glacier storage class.

Comment: Related: [Unable to restore Glacier deep archive to different S3 bucket - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878940/unable-to-restore-glacier-deep-archive-to-different-s3-bucket)

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I'm not able to deduce from the `restore_object` documentation that the only way to achieve what I want to achieve is by doing what you wrote, @AnonCoward. I don't want to restore data using the "days" approach, however, it looks like I have to. Thanks for your message :)